# How to dynamically initialize DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING in django

Tags: python, django, django-database

I have a situation that requires me to use a list of databases. One database for each tenant. This information is kept in a default database. So my `DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING` is currently hardcoded with the list of databases that I fetch manually from the default database and save it in the `settings.py` file.

But every time we upgrade our service, I need to manually copy over the database values into `DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING`. This is getting to be a pain and I'd like to build this set using code once when django initialises. Maybe have a module `dbinit.py`

```
list_of_db=[]

def initialize(defaultDbName):
   #Build up list_of_db
```

Then in `settings.py`, I can just do :-

```
import dbinit
.
.
.
DATABASE_APPS_MAPPING=dbinit.list_of_db
```

My specific question is where do I call `dbinit.initialize()` ? Is that `urls.py`, `wsgi.py`. Thanks.

Comment: Not exactly an answer to your question but you might have a look at https://django-tenant-schemas.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Comment: We use MySql, but thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have the answer here. Spent a couple of days referring to other stack overflow queries.

The code of `dbinit.py` needs to be like so:-

```
list_of_db=[]
initialized=False

def initialize(defaultDbName):
    if not initialized:
        build_up_list(list_of_db,defaultDbName)#Build the list.

initialize("mydefaultDbContainingInfoOnOtherDBs")
```

Since any imports by the python interpreter are performed while holding on to the import lock, we are assured that only one thread will be executing the code in the above module's `initialize` method. So even if the above module is imported multiple times in different threads` execution context, we are assured that the initialization has occurred only once.